# How does spectrum analyzer analyze high frequency?

Tags: frequency-spectrum

I have a question that is regarding spectrum analyzer. According to nyquist theorem, sampling rate  should be twice of maximum frequency of signal to reconstruct again. If there is a spectrum analyzer that is range 2kHz to 20GHz, is sampling rate equal 40GHz?
How to analyze high frequency component? does it pull IF frequency?

Comment: also, removed the unrelated [tag:spectral-efficiency] tag.

Comment: I read before, but is not written this issue.

Comment: Ahmet, I'm confused. You say you've read about spectrum analyzers, you even mention IF, but you can't piece this together. Could you point us at some resource you've read, so that we might base an answer on that?

Comment: I think question is so clear isn't it? there is not any thing in question about document. Also the answer is so basic, yes or no. that is all. I know how works SA but i want to know how to analyze spectrum. but you say "read hundreds documents".thank you sir.

Comment: sorry, it's not clear to me.

Comment: Consider a channel signal at 15 GHz, having a bandwidth of 100 MHz. In order to analyse that signal, you can mix it down to baseband, and sample it at 200 MHz, instead of sampling the whole spectrum from 0 to 1 GHz (at 30 GHz). So practical spectrum analysers should be following the first approach. That approach uses the critical parameter of analysis **bandwidth** which determines the sampling frequency. Look at your device documents about its analysis bandwidth to determine that.

Comment: Perfect explanation!  Thank you dear.